# See all AWS resources in/linked to a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

I am looking at a VPC in AWS that I am considering to clean up.
However, I am struggling to find out what is inside/how it is used.

Is there a way to view all resources 'inside' or 'linked to' this VPC?

Ideally I would use the AWS console, but if needed I can work via the CLI as well. I browsed around a bit, but did not find a place to identify relevant resources.

---

I am aware that I can go to individual resource types (e.g. EC2 instances) to find the ones that are linked to the VPC, but have no way to know which resource types are possibly used, there could be numerous kinds of resources in this VPC as far as I know.

Comment: I think that if you just try to delete a VPC with existing resources associated to it you will get a warning listing them.

Comment: I can’t try now, but believe it only mentioned certain types. Also this is a rather nerve wrecking way to analyze the situation but I might find myself using it anyway so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time there is no functionality to list all resources in a VPC at the moment. Generally any networking resources that reside within your VPC will have an ENI attached.

By accessing the list of [elastic network interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) you would then need to identify the applications that are bound to that ENI, some services will prefill the description with a reference to the service or resource in question. If no description exists to identify what service you will need to do this investigation yourself.

Outside of this certain resources are associated with your VPC such as internet gateway, security groups and VPNs. These will need to be identified by resource.

Comment: So, with the last paragraph you mean I would have to go through each potentially associated resource type to see if there are resources associated with my VPC? (And that there is no way to see it from the perspective of the VPC)

Comment: Yes so for internet gateway, security groups and VPNs you would need to check if these have a resource associated with the VPC (there are more). You can filter these in the API by VPC ID. These services sit under the VPC area of the console so it should be easy to identify :)

Comment: Ah, I saw the screen but a closer look suggests the VPC page indeed contains all things that can be 'in' a VPC. Even EC2 instances. It is still a bit of a detour, but at least having a 'checklist' ensures I would not forget a cost driver.

Comment: Yes the EC2 are bound to the ENIs :)

Comment: There is a deleted answer by the author of this script. I flagged for undeletion  https://github.com/dryoni/aws-tools/tree/main/eni-tool Have not tried but from the description it seems to do solve the question